# How to send an email through a web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I am developing a website and testing it on my local server by Xampp. In my website I want to send an email to a given email address that is provided by the user and the content of the email is provided by the user also. I know how to capture the data entered by the user but I can't send the email. Any help? I tried smtp but I don't want to make my email vulnerable by allowing access to less secure apps. Are here any alternatives?

Comment: If sending from your machine (localhost) then you will need to install a mail server which handles these things.

Comment: try with the swiftmailer https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: Please add some more information in your answer, That what actually you are doing here, What library you are using to send the mail,
And please attach the library link into your answer, To avoid vote down.

Comment: What is the host, username and password here:                                                       $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
$mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';              
$mail->Password   = 'secret';

Comment: @Heba These are all commented and you can see the but! the username is your gmail address the password is your gmail password the from is your gmail address the addaddress is who you want to send it to watch a youtube video on it its oging to help!

Comment: I don't want to send an email from my email address. What I want is that I have two emails given from and to and a content and I want to send the email

Comment: Do you recommend a certain video?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mercury Mail feature of XAMPP or use PHPMailer to send email from localhost.